# I want to write a SQL statement to select date range from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to write this SQL statement to select a daterange from another table and use it for filtering result.

I put together SQL statement but somehow it does not work.

Thanks for help

```
SELECT 
    a.jednota,datum, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='prijem' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as prijem_ks, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='predaj' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as predaj_ks 
FROM 
    jednotypredaj as a

SELECT 
    b.id, b.fromd, b.tod 
FROM
    datadocasne as b 
WHERE 
    (a.tovar LIKE 'kalan' AND datum BETWEEN 'b.fromd' AND 'b.tod')
GROUP BY 
    a.jednota
ORDER BY
    predaj_ks DESC
```

Table `datadocasne`:

```
id      fromt       tod
---------------------------------
1       12.4.2016     22.5.2016
```

Table `jednotypredaj`:

```
co       datum        jednota   tovar      kusy
------------------------------------------------
predaj   12.5.2016   TR003      kalan       5
predaj   25.5.2016   TR278      aechmea     6
predaj   11.4.2016   TR202      phalenopsis 8
```

Result should looks like this

```
co       datum       jednota   tovar   kusy
predaj   12.5.2016   TR003     kalan   5
```

Comment: We need to see the schema and the desired output.

Comment: which relation there is between table  a and table b?

Comment: Relation is datum  from table 1 and fromd   tod  from table 2

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your query?

Comment: Problem is that my query does not chose dates from  another table where ,are collumn like fromd   tod.  which is from date to date,  and then use sellected date for filtering results from secound table Like jednotypredaj.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the criteria in your `JOIN` clause.

```
SELECT
    J.co,
    J.datum,
    J.jednota,
    J.tovar,
    J.kusy
FROM
    datadocasne D
INNER JOIN jednotypredaj J ON J.datum BETWEEN D.fromd AND D.tod
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution if the date fields are indexed. It is also the fastest solution if no fields are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like this...

```
SELECT a.jednota,b.id,b.fromd,b.tod,
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='prijem' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as prijem_ks, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='predaj' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END) as predaj_ks 
      FROM jednotypredaj a
      join datadocasne b on a.datum between b.fromd and b.tod
 WHERE a.tovar LIKE 'kalan'
GROUP BY a.jednota,b.id,b.fromd,b.tod,
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='prijem' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END), 
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='predaj' THEN a.kusy ELSE NULL END)
ORDER by predaj_ks DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it wrote me "Invalid use of group function" when i run string

Comment: try `SUM(CASE WHEN a.co='prijem' THEN a.kusy ELSE 0 END)` replacing null with 0 ..you dont want to sum null